# Custom Module Controller Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, content-management-system, orchardcms

i'm trying to implement custom module With Orchard CMS based on ASP.net MVC that will get http request and get the respons as json data and i'm parsing it ,after that my parsed list i want to represent it in my view i have some problems while i'm calling my controller action that wil get the parsed list json data from my view i think i'm doing somthing wrong at this point can someone help me

here is my code blocks :

**Model:**

```
public class NewsDisplayRecord : ContentPartRecord
{
    public NewsDisplayRecord()
    {
        //Facebook Fields
        AppID = "*****";
        AppSecret = "*****";
        PageID = "****";

        _consumerKey = "****";
        _consumerSecret = "****";
        access_token = "***-***";
        access_token_secret = "****";

    }

    //Facebook fields
    public virtual string AppID { get; set; }
    public virtual string AppSecret { get; set; }
    public virtual string PageID { get; set; } 
    //Twitter Fields
    public virtual string _consumerKey { get; set; }
    public virtual string _consumerSecret { get; set; }
    public virtual string access_token { get; set; }
    public virtual string access_token_secret { get; set; }
    //General Fields


}

public class NewsDisplayPart : ContentPart<NewsDisplayRecord>
{
    public string AppID
    {
        get { return Retrieve(r => r.AppID); }
        set { Store(r => r.AppID, value); }
    }
    public string AppSecret
    {
        get { return Retrieve(r => r.AppSecret); }
        set { Store(r => r.AppSecret, value); }
    }
    public string PageID
    {
        get { return Retrieve(r => r.PageID); }
        set { Store(r => r.PageID, value); }
    }
    public string _consumerKey
    {
        get { return Retrieve(r => r._consumerKey); }
        set { Store(r => r._consumerKey, value); }
    }
    public string _consumerSecret
    {
        get { return Retrieve(r => r._consumerSecret); }
        set { Store(r => r._consumerSecret, value); }
    }
    public string access_token
    {
        get { return Retrieve(r => r.access_token); }
        set { Store(r => r.access_token, value); }
    }
    public string access_token_secret
    {
        get { return Retrieve(r => r.access_token_secret); }
        set { Store(r => r.access_token_secret, value); }
    }


}
```

Controller:

```
 public class SocialFeeds : Controller
{
    private readonly ISocialService _socialservice;
    private readonly IOrchardServices _services;


    SocialFeeds(ISocialService socialservice)
    {
        _socialservice = socialservice;

    }
    SocialFeeds(ISocialService socialservice, IOrchardServices services)
    {
        _socialservice = socialservice;
        _services = services;
    }

    // GET: /SocialFeeds/
    public ActionResult GetFeeds() {

        var feedslist =this._socialservice.getfeeds_facebook();
        if (feedslist == null)
        {
            return this.HttpNotFound();
        }

        return View(feedslist);
    }

    public string Index()
    {
        var feedslist = this._socialservice.getfeeds_facebook();

        return feedslist.ToString();
    }
}
```

Services:

```
public interface ISocialService : IDependency
{
     string getToken();
     string getWebResponse(string url);
     List<feed> getfeeds_facebook();
}

public class SocialService : ISocialService
{
    public NewsDisplayRecord Social = new NewsDisplayRecord();
    public string getToken()
    {
        string facebookurl = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={0}&client_secret={1}&grant_type=client_credentials", Social.AppID, Social.AppSecret);
        return getWebResponse(facebookurl);
    }
    public string getWebResponse(string url)
    {
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        return reader.ReadToEnd();

    }

    public List<feed> getfeeds_facebook()
    {
        string feedurl = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/{0}/feed?{1}", Social.PageID, getToken());
        string output = getWebResponse(feedurl);
        var converter = new ExpandoObjectConverter();
        dynamic message = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(output, converter);
        List<feed> list = new List<feed>();
        foreach (var item in message.data)
        {

            if (item.type == "photo")
            {
                feed f = new feed()
                {
                    created_time = Convert.ToDateTime(item.created_time.ToString().Replace("T", " ").Replace("+0000", "")),
                    icon = item.icon,
                    link = item.link,
                    message = item.message,
                    object_id = item.object_id,
                    picture = item.picture,
                    id = item.id,
                    bigpicture = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/{0}/picture", item.object_id)
                };
                f.likes = new List<user>();
                foreach (var j in item.likes.data)
                {
                    f.likes.Add(new user() { id = j.id, name = j.name });
                }
                list.Add(f);
            }
        }
        return list;
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model NewsDisplay.Models.NewsDisplayPart
@{
var feed1 = Html.Action("GetFeeds", "SocialFeeds");
}

<fieldset>
<h1>feed1</h1>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Can you post the error? Your controller has 2 constructors, that could cause problems.

Comment: Can you please provide error details?